# How to trigger java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class XXXX

Tags: java, exception

Rarely I get this error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class XXXX` when starting tomcat. It is caused by one of my classes. I have a static variable that gets the user agent in a wicket context in that class (``). I was wondering how I could consistently trigger this exception so as to be able to fix it.